# VBA Click and Type on XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if I can type and click on a web page using XMLHTTP. For example I would like to go to Yahoo Finance and type something in the search bar and hit submit.

I would not like to use internet explorer, instead to use XMLHTTP. And I am not looking to just concatenate URLs. Here is what I have:

```
Dim XHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTTPCol, HTTPCol2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTTPEl As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

XHTTP.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/", False
XHTTP.send

If XHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
 MsgBox "Problem"
 Exit Sub
 End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XHTTP.responseText

Set HTTPCol = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("yfin-usr-qry")

For Each  HTTPEl In HTTPCol 
IDTarget.Value = "AAPL"
Next

Set HTTPCol2  = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("search-button")

Set HTTPCol2(0).Click

'But then the "click" does submit to go to the next page where I can grab data from this page. I would like to, for example, get the stock price of apple on this new page.
```

Comment: You need to use a browser if you plan on interacting in this way unless there is the action of click is associated with  an url you can grab without the click and feed to a New xmlhttp request

Comment: It is likely that typing and clicking actually leads to a new url (query string) being used in navigation bar of browser (or xhr visible in network tab) - mimic that from your source variables and pass that as GET url in xmlhttp.

Comment: @QHarr does clicking and typing even work on the XMLHTTP? I will have to figure out a way to test it, being that I can't actually see it by making a browser visible

Comment: @QHarr         does clicking and typing even work on the XMLHTTP? I will have to figure out a way to test it, being that I can't actually see it by making a browser visible

Comment: You would need to use a browser first for click and type

Comment: @QHarr         I don't believe so, I think I can use a POST method to submit data to a web server. This is not clicking and typing but it will still do the trick of submitting data to a website. I am having troubles learning this although, does that make sense to you?

Comment: My point was you can concantenate the ticker into the url you submit via GET so  no click and text entry required e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch  Pretty sure this is a duplicate I have answered at some point on this site so perhaps have a look and see if that will help.

Comment: @QHarr         Right, but I am trying to do this without concatenating the URL